# Spring Boot Testing Thymeleaf org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, thymeleaf

I am trying to test a controller but it always gives me the following Thymeleaf TemplateProcessingException:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "car.name" (template: "checkout" - line 56, col 35)

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class BookingController {

    @Autowired
    private BookingService bookingService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private BookingExtraService bookingExtraService;
    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

 @PostMapping("/checkout")
    public String checkout(@RequestParam(required = false) List<Long> selectedExtras,
                           @RequestParam String userName,
                           @RequestParam String startAddress,
                           @RequestParam String goalAddress,
                           @RequestParam String dateOfTrip,
                           @RequestParam String timeOfTrip,
                           @RequestParam Integer numberOfPeople,
                           Model model,
                           HttpSession session){

        session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
        session.setAttribute("startAddress", startAddress);
        session.setAttribute("goalAddress", goalAddress);
        session.setAttribute("dateOfTrip", dateOfTrip);
        session.setAttribute("timeOfTrip", timeOfTrip);
        session.setAttribute("numberOfPeople", numberOfPeople);

        List<BookingExtra> extras = new ArrayList<>();

        if(selectedExtras != null) {
            session.setAttribute("selectedExtras", selectedExtras);
            for (Long extraId : selectedExtras) {
                extras.add(bookingExtraService.findById(extraId));
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("extras", extras);

        Car car = carService.findById((Long) session.getAttribute("selectedCar"));
        model.addAttribute("car", car);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        String priceTotalString = df.format(bookingService.calculatePrice(extras, car));
        model.addAttribute("priceTotal", priceTotalString);

        return "checkout";
    }
```

This is my view "checkout":

```
<body>
    <navbar th:insert="fragments.html :: navbar"></navbar>
    <div class="div-gap"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container" style="width: 800px">
            <h3>Zusammenfassung</h3>
            <br>

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Extra:</th>
                        <th scope="col">Preis:</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:if="${extras.empty}">
                        <td>keine Extras ausgewählt</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr th:each="extra : ${extras}">
                        <td th:text="${extra.name}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${extra.price} + ' €'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>+ Grundpreis Auto
                            <span th:text="' (' +${car.name} + ')'"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td th:text="${car.basePrice} + ' €'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="fs-4 fw-bold">Gesamt:</td>
                        <td class="fs-4 fw-bold" th:text="${priceTotal} + '€'"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <form th:action="@{/savebooking}" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="dateOfTrip" th:value="${session.dateOfTrip}">
                <input type="hidden" name="timeOfTrip" th:value="${session.timeOfTrip}">
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary fs-5 fw-bold">Buchen</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my test class:

```
@WebMvcTest(BookingController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class BookingControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BookingService bookingServiceMock;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userServiceMock;

    @MockBean
    private BookingExtraService bookingExtraServiceMock;

    @MockBean
    private CarService carServiceMock;

    private static MockHttpServletRequest request;


    @MockBean
    private Car car;

    @MockBean
    private CarImage carImage;


    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup(){
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.setParameter("userName", "test@test.de");
        request.setParameter("startAddress", "Testaddress");
        request.setParameter("goalAddress", "Testaddress");
        request.setParameter("dateOfTrip", "2022/08/01");
        request.setParameter("timeOfTrip", "08:00");
        request.setParameter("numberOfPeople", "8");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnCheckout() throws Exception{

        when(carServiceMock.findById(1L)).thenReturn(car);

        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/checkout")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("userName", request.getParameter("userName"))
                        .param("startAddress", request.getParameter("startAddress"))
                        .param("goalAddress", request.getParameter("goalAddress"))
                        .param("dateOfTrip", request.getParameter("dateOfTrip"))
                        .param("timeOfTrip", request.getParameter("timeOfTrip"))
                        .param("numberOfPeople", request.getParameter("numberOfPeople")))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        ModelAndViewAssert.assertViewName(mvcResult.getModelAndView(), "checkout");
    }
```

What I've already tried:

- Setting Expectations for car.name and car.getname() with when().thenReturn()
- Loading the whole ApplicationContext with @SpringBootTest and instead of @WebMvcTest
- Creating a new Car instance and returning it with thenReturn() instead of the mocked Car instance
- Searching the internet for 2 days for a possible solution

Can anyone please point me in the right direction what I am missing here?

EDIT: Complete Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "car.name" (template: "checkout" - line 56, col 35)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:199)
    at de.akad.web43.Controller.BookingControllerTest.shouldReturnCheckout(BookingControllerTest.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "car.name" (template: "checkout" - line 56, col 35)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.AdditionExpression.executeAddition(AdditionExpression.java:96)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.ComplexExpression.executeComplex(ComplexExpression.java:62)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:112)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.AdditionExpression.executeAddition(AdditionExpression.java:89)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.ComplexExpression.executeComplex(ComplexExpression.java:62)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:112)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.render(TestDispatcherServlet.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
    ... 106 more
```

**SOLUTION**

Since

```
carServices.findId((Long) session.getAttribute("selectedCar")
```

needs the session attribute to return Car properly, I could resolve the issue by adding this attribute to the mocked session. My adjusted test is as follows:

```
 @Test
    public void shouldReturnCheckout() throws Exception{

        when(carServiceMock.findById(1L)).thenReturn(car);

        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/checkout")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("userName", request.getParameter("userName"))
                        .param("startAddress", request.getParameter("startAddress"))
                        .param("goalAddress", request.getParameter("goalAddress"))
                        .param("dateOfTrip", request.getParameter("dateOfTrip"))
                        .param("timeOfTrip", request.getParameter("timeOfTrip"))
                        .param("numberOfPeople", request.getParameter("numberOfPeople"))
                        .sessionAttr("selectedCar", 1L))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        ModelAndViewAssert.assertViewName(mvcResult.getModelAndView(), "checkout");
}
```

Comment: Share the complete stacktrace to identify more about the problem.

Comment: @Rishal I've edited my original post and included the stacktrace

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null` you have name as null in your object. Check if its value is coming properly.

Comment: From my understanding 'name' is coming properly. It's displayed in the actual application and if I use the debugger for the test case I can read it as well. It seems like Thymeleaf isn't receiving my mocked Car object. But I can't figure out why

Comment: can you please share your car class details?

Comment: I could finally resolve the issue by adding the session attribute that is used by the carService to return the car object to the mocked session. Now everything works. I included the solution in my original post. Thank you for your help Rishal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:
> Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null

Meaning your `car` object is returning as null *mostly* as a part of this call in `BookingController` :

```
Car car = carService.findById((Long) session.getAttribute("selectedCar"));
```

Can you recheck if your `carService` is returning any car object at all at this point.

If you managed to add proper non-null `car` attribute to model, your issue will get resolved for "car.name" as well as for "car.basePrice".

If in some cases, `car` used to return null, then you might need to use conditions something like this -

```
 <div th:if= "${car!=null}">
  //then access cars properties
```

Comment: I could finally resolve the issue by adding the attribute "selectecCar" to the mocked session. I guess the mocked carService couldn't return a car object, because the session attribut was missing. In the actual application the user choses a car from a gallery and the corresponding id is saved in the session as "selectedCar". Since the gallery is only showing existing cars, the id would always point to an existing car. So car can never be null. THANK YOU for your help. You hint helped me to find a solution!

Comment: glad it worked for you! :-) :-)